# Oauth Consent Page Does Not Display Product Name That is Configured in "Oauth consent screen"

Tags: google-oauth

We notice that the consent page displayed to user no longer show our product name(Adpoint Development) as configured in the consent configuration. Instead, our homepage mbww.com is shown. We're concerned that this might affect the approval(Oauth Developer Verification https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification?query=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly) that we're in the process of getting.

[image: Consent page displayed to user]

[image: Consent page displayed to user]

[image: product name configured]

Comment: I dont think this will effect your approval it looks like a change from within Google.  However i have pinged someone on the team to see what they have to say.

Comment: Even i have the same problem, i dont want my domain name to be shown, instead i want my product name to be shown.